# Change Selected Image Bug In Swift

Tags: swift, button, selected

I have a Button and want to change the selected image.
But after change the image of the button.
There show a blue point on the button.

[After Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieVwo.jpg)

[Before Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ZmM.jpg)

```
@IBAction func VideoShowBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    if VideoShowOutlet.selected {
        playerVideo.hidden = false
        VideoShowOutlet.selected = !VideoShowOutlet.selected
    } else {
        playerVideo.hidden = true
        VideoShowOutlet.selected = !VideoShowOutlet.selected
    }

    playerVideo.play()
}
```

But with the same code.
Some button won't shows the blue point.

```
@IBAction func ShareContentShowBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    if ShareContentShowOutlet.selected {
        ShareVideoURLTF.hidden = false
        ShareVideoContentTV.hidden = false
        ShareContentShowOutlet.selected = !ShareContentShowOutlet.selected
    } else {
        ShareVideoURLTF.hidden = true
        ShareVideoContentTV.hidden = true
        ShareContentShowOutlet.selected = !ShareContentShowOutlet.selected
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project using Command - Shift - K and then running it again? Sometimes this helps.

Comment: I had try this before.It does not work.Thank your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way to solve it: 
Set **tintColor** to **clearColor**, on StoryBoard:
[image]

Or programmatically:

```
VideoShowOutlet.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Thank you!Thank you!Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was correct, can you please mark it as so?